# How can I show a graph using d3 force layout with initial positions set and no movement at all?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I use d3 force layout to construct a graph, and then store the positions of the nodes in a database.

The next time I want to show the graph, I read the positions from the database into the nodes and then I start the force layout.

That causes the layout to move slightly.

Is there I way to show the graph with the stored node positions without calling force.start() at all?

What I want is a "read only" mode to show a stable graph created by someone else earlier.

/Hans

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend you to read the [documentation of the force layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout). It is really good.

As you mentioned, you have to set the `px` and `py` attributes for each node. Then, you can set the attribute `fixed` to `true` in each node.

This will imply that computing force.start() won't have any effect.

---

Another thing you can try is to set the alpha value to 0, and then start the simulation:

```
force.alpha(0)
    .start()
```

I am not sure whether this method works. Post a jsFiddle if it does not.

Comment: Oh I've read the documentation back and forth, but I'm just not clever enough to realize that I should use the fixed attribute :-).

It works great!
Thanks!

Comment: That's normal don't worry. I am glad it helped. You can accept the answer if it solved your problem.